# automatic form reset in vb.net after game has ended

Tags: vb.net

After the game has ended i want my form to reset automatically. here is what i have so far.

```
 If wrongguess = 6 Then
            MsgBox("gameover bad luck!!!")


            End
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this is  use `Application.Restart()` instead of `End`. That will restart your application.

Complex way is change MainForm property of ApplicationContext instance before closing your start up form.
To do this, you need change many part of your program . Change project settings,  create `Sub Main` by hand , create 
[ApplicationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance and more.

Comment: Im now getting this error ....Warning 1 Could not copy "obj\x86\Debug\HANGMAN-SHAPES V100.exe" to "bin\Debug\HANGMAN-SHAPES V100.exe". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\HANGMAN-SHAPES V100.exe' because it is being used by another process. HANGMAN-SHAPES V100

Comment: @user3469896 you need close your application (HANDMAN-SHAPES V100.exe) before you build or start debug. if you already closed your application, use windows taskmanager to check your application's process still running.